# Get a random record using Django ORM

Tags: sql, django-models, orm

I need help converting this raw sql query:

```
Hotels.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM HotelAPP_hotels WHERE City = %s ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1',[City]);
```

Comment: You want to convert this sql query in what?

Answer (score 1):

A clear and quick solution would be to do like this.

```
Hotels.objects.filter(City = City).exclude(id = id).order_by('?')[:1]
```

order_by('?') randomly order your query set.

Answer (score -1):

**Seem to have figured it out**

*Get queryset which is filtered by a column , in my case city . In my case I am also excluding the original hotel from this set.*

```
NearbyHotels = Hotels.objects.filter(City = City).exclude(id = id)
```

*Name a list*

```
Nearbyid = []
```

*Add the id of each retrieved object into the list*

```
for Hotel in NearbyHotels:
        Nearbyid.append(Hotel.id)
```

*Pick a random ID*

```
randomid = random.choice(Nearbyid)
```

*Retrieve a single object matching the random id*

```
Recommendation = Hotels.objects.get(id = randomid)
```

**And that is how I am pulling a random hotel in the same city as the original hotel.**